# Rails ActionController::MissingExactTemplate Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting out using rails and I've come a across an issue I can't seem to solve or find the solution to. For some reason when I opened up the project today I kept getting this error

```
ActionController::MissingExactTemplate (HomeController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html)
```

This is my home_controller.rb under app/controllers

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

This is my index.html.erb under app/views/home

```html
<p>Index</p>
```

my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
end
```

I've also run rails app:update, to no success. I've looked around stackoverflow and other websites but can't seem to find a solution that has worked for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For giggles, can you add `resources :home` to your routes.rb file under the `root` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it just works now? I went away for a day came back and it works. I have a feeling it has something to do with me running this on a Windows machine, I've head of issues with Ruby on Rails and Windows, I'm believe I'll just setup a Linux VM to mitigate issues like this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your issue with the setup you have described but the issue does not appear to me.

What the bug tells you is that Rails can't find the view associated with the controller function, which urges me to believe that the index.html.erb file is not in app/views/home, but in app/views/layouts/home. (empirically speaking, I did the same error when creating the project)

Comment: That’s not the issue, it is in the app/views/home directory. I can always remake the project from scratch  I’m not to far along, however I would like to understand what’s going on here